Handling Multiple Parameter Extraction and Conditional Fulfillment in Dialogflow CX
I'm working with Dialogflow CX and encountering an issue where only one parameter is being extracted from user input, which causes the agent to repeatedly ask for the second parameter. I need to capture all relevant parameters from the start to ensure accurate fulfillment.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Created two parameters and added respective fulfillment responses.
Tested the setup, but noticed that only the first parameter is being extracted, and the agent keeps asking for the second parameter.
The main idea is that I want the agent to capture all the entities from start to end. For instance, a user might provide information for both parameters in a single response. In my case, if the user answers the question for the second parameter, it should be extracted and fulfill the intent accordingly.
Example Conditional Fullfilment:
enter image description here page with parameters and parameter Initial prompt fulfillment.
if $session.params.date = null
  Can you provide the date?
elif $session.params.time = null
  Can you provide the time?
else
  Thank you provide me date and time.
endif

Entities: Date and Time
Scenario 1: User says "12-12-2023" — the agent asks for the time. When the user says "7 PM," the agent responds with a thanks message. Here, each parameter is extracted separately.
Scenario 2: User says "12-12-2023 7 PM" — the agent should extract both the date and the time in one go. However, in my current setup, only the date is being extracted, and the agent continues to ask for the time, instead of responding with a thanks message.
How can I configure Dialogflow CX to ensure that it captures all parameters from a single user response and processes them correctly?

Hi @Alen, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

You can use the below steps:
1.Try using the dialogflow cx system entities to get the time and date - @sys.date-time or for separately collecting - @sys.date , @sys.time
2.Use the training phrases for the intent depending on your input collection sequence. For example:
"The date i want is 02-september-2024 and time 4:30 PM"
select and mark the date as @sys.date type and time as @sys.time
Add at least 5-6 training phrases with the possible user inputs in the intent.

Thanks for the response. My main problem is ..How can Dialogflow CX be configured so that if a user provides a response to a parameter early in the conversation, the system will remember and utilize this response at a future step in the dialog flow?

The dialogflow CX can use the intent as Route to specify the parameter which needs to be extracted.
You can add different training phrases including both parameters and single parameter in a single intent. Then later on, you can use the Condition in the Route to check if both the parameters have been assigned the value or not. You can use : $session.params.your_variable_name !=null OR $session.params.your_variable_name.status ="UPDATED"
If both the values has been assigned then you may proceed as per your logic and if not then you can ask to input the particular value.
